# How do I use variable created in a scope outside of it or at least a way around this

Tags: c#

I have been working on this one assignment for two weeks now and I can't figure it out. I have seen some things on here that mention using classes and methods but in the assignment instructions it says not to use them since we haven't learned it yet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;
namespace Assignment_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Write("Enter a salesperson's name: ");
            string name = ReadLine();

            do
            {
                Write("\n" + "Enter an item number between 1 and 4 or -1 to quit: ");
                String item = ReadLine();
                int intItem = Convert.ToInt32(item);

                Write("\n" + "Enter the quantity sold: ");
                String quantity = ReadLine();
                int intQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantity);

                switch (intItem)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            Double price = 239.99;
                            double total = price * intQuantity;
                            WriteLine("Salesperson " + name + " sold " + intQuantity + " of item #" + intItem + " at $" + total);
                            double dblTotalSales = +total;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                            Double price = 129.75;
                            double total = price * intQuantity;
                            WriteLine("Salesperson " + name + " sold " + intQuantity + " of item #" + intItem + " at $" + total);
                            double dblTotalSales = +total;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 3:
                        {
                            Double price = 99.95;
                            double total = price * intQuantity;
                            WriteLine("Salesperson " + name + " sold " + intQuantity + " of item #" + intItem + " at $" + total);
                            double dblTotalSales = +total;
                            break;
                        }
                    case 4:
                        {
                            Double price = 350.89;
                            double total = price * intQuantity;
                            WriteLine("Salesperson " + name + " sold " + intQuantity + " of item #" + intItem + " at $" + total);
                            double dblTotalSales = +total;
                            break;
                        }
                    case -1:
                        {
                            WriteLine("Salesperson " + name + " sold a total of $" + dblTotalSales);
                            break;
                        }
                }

            } while (true);  

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare the variable in the scope where you need it.

Comment: All those variables which you declare over and over and over, do it *once* before the start of the `switch` block.  As is, you are creating *multiple* price variables which are only available in that indented block.

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION (once you start seriously using classes, vs. simple variables in "static Main()"): consider a [class property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the variable `dblTotalSales`.
You are declaring the variable as a new variable inside each case of your switch statement, which means it is scoped to ONLY the specific case where it is declared.

If you are wanting to make the variable accessible to all of the case's, the variable needs to be declared outside the scope of the switch statement:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;
namespace Assignment_2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Write("Enter a salesperson's name: ");
        string name = ReadLine();

        // declare here to be outside the scope of the loop, 
        // but accessible to everything inside the loop.
        double dblTotalSales = 0;

        do
        {
            Write("\n" + "Enter an item number between 1 and 4 or -1 to quit: ");
            String item = ReadLine();
            int intItem = Convert.ToInt32(item);

            Write("\n" + "Enter the quantity sold: ");
            String quantity = ReadLine();
            int intQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantity);

            switch (intItem)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Double price = 239.99;
                        double total = price * intQuantity;
                        WriteLine("Salesperson " + name + " sold " + intQuantity + " of item #" + intItem + " at $" + total);
                        // now just reference the previously declared variable
                        dblTotalSales = +total;
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        Double price = 129.75;
                        double total = price * intQuantity;
                        WriteLine("Salesperson " + name + " sold " + intQuantity + " of item #" + intItem + " at $" + total);
                        // now just reference the previously declared variable
                        dblTotalSales = +total;
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        Double price = 99.95;
                        double total = price * intQuantity;
                        WriteLine("Salesperson " + name + " sold " + intQuantity + " of item #" + intItem + " at $" + total);
                        // now just reference the previously declared variable
                        dblTotalSales = +total;
                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    {
                        Double price = 350.89;
                        double total = price * intQuantity;
                        WriteLine("Salesperson " + name + " sold " + intQuantity + " of item #" + intItem + " at $" + total);
                        // now just reference the previously declared variable
                        dblTotalSales = +total;
                        break;
                    }
                case -1:
                    {
                        WriteLine("Salesperson " + name + " sold a total of $" + dblTotalSales);
                        break;
                    }
            }

        } while (true);  

    }
```

Comment: I've updated my code and it works a lot better now. I've got another question though. How do I set dblTotal to be the entire total of everything. So when I get a new price it'll add to dblTotal instead of resetting it back to just the price.

Comment: The variable dblTotalSales is being SET to total in each case. Change this from `dblTotalSales = +total;` to `dblTotalSales += total;` in all cases.
This will add the value of `total` to `dblTotalSales` instead of assigning the value of `total` to the variable `dblTotalSales`.

Comment: @Samuel Pressley - You have a few bugs in this assignment btw. Your quit logic is flawed and doesn't work, and it may pay to log the accumulating total for each case to make sure your code (and math) is working correctly for both the choice with individual total, as well as the overall total.